# Create Panels based on GridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gridview, panel

I am making an application, in which it is necessary to create a list with several options, in this case the list includes measure of the item and its position.
The position refers to the fact that within a Panel, there are positions A, B, C, D, and each item must occupy one of those positions as marked in the GridView list.

It should be as follows.

[image: Panels and GridView]

I create a code, but is not connected with the GridView and create the objects based on the number of units created in the gridview.

```
 For i = 1 To ContadorIzq

            pos = CInt(TextBox38.Text)
            poslabel = CInt(TextBox42.Text)

            Dim pb As New Panel With
            {
                .Width = 120,
                .Height = 460,
                .Top = 10,
                .Left = 10,
                .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                .BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\Images\sections\Ejem.bmp"),
                .BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
                .ContextMenuStrip = CntxtMnuStrpUnit,
                .Name = "Panel" & CInt(TextBox37.Text),
                .Location = New Point(pos, 20)
            }

            AddHandler pb.Click, AddressOf myClickHandler_b

            Dim labela As New Label With {
                .AutoSize = True,
                .Location = New Point((poslabel), 12),
                .Text = "Section " & CInt(TextBox37.Text),
                .ForeColor = Color.White,
                .BackColor = Color.Transparent,
                .Font = New Font(Me.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                .Name = "Label" & CInt(TextBox37.Text)
            }

            AddHandler labela.Click, AddressOf myClickHandler

            labela.Font = New Font(labela.Font, FontStyle.Bold)

            Panel1.Controls.Add(pb)
            pb.Controls.Add(labela)

            Dim posY As Int16 = 30
            Dim posX As Int16 = 3

            For j = 1 To 4

                If j = 1 Then

                    Dim pbdoors As New Panel With {
                        .Width = 114,
                        .Height = 198,
                        .Top = 10,
                        .Left = 10,
                        .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                        .BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\Images\Doors\EjemB.bmp"),
                        .BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
                        .ContextMenuStrip = CntxtMnuStrpUnit,
                        .Name = "Panel" & CInt(TextBox37.Text) & j
                    }

                    AddHandler pbdoors.Click, AddressOf myClickHandler_doors

                    pbdoors.Location = New Point(posX, 30)
                    pb.Controls.Add(pbdoors)
                    posY = (posY + 100)

                ElseIf j = 2 Then

                    posY = 130

                ElseIf j = 3 Then

                    Dim pbdoors As New Panel With {
                        .Width = 114,
                        .Height = 98,
                        .Top = 10,
                        .Left = 10,
                        .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                        .BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\Images\Doors\EjemC.bmp"),
                        .BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
                        .ContextMenuStrip = CntxtMnuStrpUnit,
                        .Name = "Panel" & CInt(TextBox37.Text) & j
                    }

                    AddHandler pbdoors.Click, AddressOf myClickHandler_doors

                    pbdoors.Location = New Point(posX, 230)
                    pb.Controls.Add(pbdoors)
                    posY = (posY + 100)

                ElseIf j = 4 Then

                    Dim pbdoors As New Panel With {
                        .Width = 114,
                        .Height = 98,
                        .Top = 10,
                        .Left = 10,
                        .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                        .BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\Images\Doors\EjemC2.bmp"),
                        .BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
                        .ContextMenuStrip = CntxtMnuStrpUnit,
                        .Name = "Panel" & CInt(TextBox37.Text) & j
                    }

                    AddHandler pbdoors.Click, AddressOf myClickHandler_doors

                    pbdoors.Location = New Point(posX, 330)
                    pb.Controls.Add(pbdoors)
                    posY = (posY + 100)

                End If

            Next

            TextBox38.Text = pos + 120
            TextBox37.Text = CInt(TextBox37.Text) + 1
            TextBox40.Text = CInt(TextBox40.Text) + 120

        Next
```

Please, any idea?, could you help me please?

Comment: There is no standard `GridView` control in WinForms. Either you're using a third-party control, or you're not using WinForms, or you're not using a `GridView`. There is a WinForms `DataGridView` control. Is that what you're using? Names are important so please make the minimal effort to use the right one. Other controls with similar names will work differently and thus require different solutions.

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you're actually trying to achieve here. I don;t see why you would be creating controls at run time rather than just creating them at design time and then display the appropriate text in the appropriate place at run time.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thank you for your answer. Yes, is a GridView, the GridView is inside a GridContro, Im using DevExpress to create this, but is Winform without hesitation. And about of how I create the objects, I do this at runtime, because the user must be able to move the data as deemed necessary at runtime.